# Creating SQL View that checks for data in multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, view

So I have a sql table that will hold an ID like so

```
---------------------------------------------------
| RecordID | Date | Price
--------------------------------------------------
| 1 | 8/31/2016 | 49
--------------------------------------------------
| 2 | 8/31/2016 | 101
--------------------------------------------------
```

And I have 3 other tables that will hold information about this ID and can have different amount of columns

```
Table 1
---------------------------------------------------
| RecordID | Date | Price | Name
--------------------------------------------------
| 1 | 8/31/2016 | 50 | System
--------------------------------------------------
Table 2
---------------------------------------------------
| RecordID | Date | Price | Coupon
--------------------------------------------------
| 2 | 8/31/2016 | 100 | 7
--------------------------------------------------
```

but the IDs are split between them. Meaning table 1 can have ID 1 then table 2 can have ID 2 and so on. An ID can only exist in one of the three tables.

So my desire is to create a view where i can get the ID and price from the original table and find which table this ID exists in and put it all together nicely like this

```
---------------------------------------------------
| RecordID | Date | Price1 | Price2
--------------------------------------------------
| 1 | 8/31/2016 | 49 | 50
--------------------------------------------------
| 2 | 8/31/2016 | 101 | 100
--------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `LEFT OUTER JOINS` and `coalesce`.

Assuming you have a main table called `tRecords` and 3 other tables called `tInfo1`, `tInfo2` and `tInfo3`, all of which have a `RecordID` and `Price` columns:

```
SELECT 
    A.RecordID
    ,A.[Date]
    ,A.Price AS Price1
    ,COALESCE(B.Price,C.Price,D.Price) AS Price2
FROM
    tRecords A
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tInfo1 B
       ON A.RecordID = B.RecordID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tInfo2 C
       ON A.RecordID = C.RecordID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tInfo3 D
       ON A.RecordID = D.RecordID
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the type of data you have in your tables, consider creating a View to combine the results of your 3 other tables, to make a virtual combination table:

```
create view vRecordCombo
select RecordId, Date, Price, Name as 'InfoString', NULL as 'InfoValue'
from table1
UNION ALL
select RecordId, Date, Price, NULL as 'InfoString', Coupon as 'InfoValue'
from table2
```

Then you can do joins on the combo as if it's a single table containing all your records.